# System out of memory exception on 64bit machine?

Tags: asp.net, memory, 64-bit, out-of-memory

I have an asp.net application with other 6 class library projects. In one of my class library project which main one, I cache some static DB tables. Webdev.webserver40.exe reaches about 1,5 gb and It throws "System out of memory exception". I know that on 32 bit machine I am limited up to 2 gb of process size but my developer machine is 64bit and 64 bit shouldnt have limitation. OK, I see that you are saying your Asp.net application will run 32 bit anyway even though I have 64bit machine. Therefore I am getting the exception. But what can I do to resolve that issue?

- I opened configuration manager and tried to change all class libraries as x64 but I am not able to change my main website project. that's why 64 references arent recognized on 32bit website.

Please don't tell me that I should do local DB or some other options instead of caching into memory :) Ok, these are also other options but firs I would like to know if there is anyway to that in the memory.I need to have cache more than 2gb even.

PS, what is that "Enable the VS hosting process" option under Debug tab. does it affecting my problem? I tried checking and unchecking and nothing changed. Indeed looks like checking it works better but I still get the exception.

EDIT 1: As I found that post, it tells me that if have 32 bit application running on 64 bit OS, I should have 2800 mb max. process size but why it doesn't allow me to that and throws exception at around 1500mb.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/10/chat-question-memory-limits-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-processes.aspx

EDIT 2: I tried adding that code in app.config of class library in which I do caching as well as into the web.config as suggested on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28VS.110%29.aspx) it says only  framework 4.5 but I use 4.0. Is there similar hack on 4.0? because I am not sure if I should install and start using 4.5 while it is not last release.

```
<runtime>
  <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

thanks for your help.
Regards.

Comment: If one or more of your references is 32-bit only, your whole site will be 32-bit.  It doesn't matter that you're on a 64-bit computer, that process is still limited to a 32-bit address space.  That space needs to coexist with the OS, so it still takes its standard share of memory.

Comment: Can you verify that you're using a 32-bit assembly reference?

Comment: @Aristos: are you talking about application pool? I meant on local debugging, so my questions isnt related to IIS.

Comment: My web application is running 32 bit. I checked it with processexplorer. But am I able to change that running 64 because it is a web app not a windows app? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your IIS express to run 64bit in visual studio:

Go to Visual Studio - Tools - Options Menu

Choose: - Projects and Solutions, then Web Projects

tick the checkbox: "User the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"

No Registry edit necessary.

Comment: this is finally the answer with VS2015. Earlier versions of VS didnt allow this. Unfortunate with this is if you occupy so much memory and you want to figure out what is holding that much memory, It is almost impossible to take a memory snapshot as you will get out of memory exception during the snapshot as well. VS2015 enterprise has the option to analyze a memory dump file which is the only available option looks like. Redgate memory analyzer can be also other option

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken, but I do believe that `Webdev.webserver40.exe` (a.k.a. Cassini) is a 32-bit native C++ application.

In your asp.net web project properties page, check the box that says "Use IIS Express" and see if that resolves your issue

EDIT: 
Check these things as well -

1. check that you do actually have enough RAM to hold your data
2. ensure that you have enough free HDD space on your swap file drive
3. determine whether your swap file is dynamic or fixed sized

Comment: Yes I was just thinking about iis express.  I will try later and let you know. Thanks

Comment: You may also want to consider trying it in full-blown IIS (if IISExpress doesn't work) since it may have a better (pardon the pun) handle on the memory situation

Comment: IIS express 8 has only 64 bit support I believe but I still couldnt figure out how to debug 64 bit? everytime when I debug I see my issexpress.exe has 32* on task manager? any suggestion? thanks